# The Kiddush Levana Jump

Tags: halacha, tefilla, kiddush-levanah, dance, tractate-soferim

What type of 'dance' is an individual reciting Kiddush Levana supposed to do at [this](http://opensiddur.org/prayers-for/new-moons/kiddush-levanah-sanctification-of-the-moon-rabbi-david-seidenberg-neohasid-org/) point?

> כְּשֵׁם שֶׁאֲנִי רוֹקֵד כְּנֶגְדֵּךְ וְאֵינִי יָכוֹל לִנְגּוֹעַ בָּךְ,
>   כַּךְ לֹא יוּכְלוּ כָּל אוֹיְבים לִנְגוֹעַ בָּהֶם לְרָעָה.
>
> Just as I leap (and dance) opposite you and cannot touch you, so may
>   enemies be unable to touch each other for harm

Based on [Maseches Soferim](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Soferim.20.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (20:2):

> ואומר ג"פ סימן טוב סימן טוב [תהיה] לכל ישראל ברוך יוצרך ברוך עושך ברוך
>   קונך ברוך בוראך **ורוקד ג׳ רקידות כנגדה ואומר** ג"פ כשם שאני רוקד כנגדך
>   ואיני נוגע ביך כך אם ירקדו אחרים כנגדי [להזיקני] לא יגעו בי תפול עליהם
>   אימתה ופחד ולמפרע אמן אמן סלה הללויה

People seem to have different methods of jumping, quasi-dancing, raising to the tips of their toes, or nothing at all - does any sefer/posek discuss what to do particularly?

Comment: This is just a Minhag. Whatever everyone else is doing should by definition be appropriate.

Comment: [Depends on how many people are around.](https://youtu.be/8_h4pN2yPag?t=9m30s)

Comment: @IsaacMoses https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuTS_xNWH8I

Comment: Isaac has a point. Most people I've seen do the "Kedusha tiptoe" and I have seen a group do the "yeshiva shuffle" (i.e. they shove each other in a crowded circle as they do at a simcha.)

Answer (score 1):

The Rema  mentions dancing during Kiddush Levana

The Mishnah Berurah (426:14) writes in the name of Achronim that one should only dance during Kiddush Levana but be careful not to bow, as that would give the appearance that one is bowing toward the moon. He also mentions rising to the tips of your toes in the context of dancing.